# Convert a slice of interface to an io.Reader object in golang?

Tags: json, api, go

I am trying to do this data conversion but I am stuck. I have this json request body:

```json
{
    "city": "XYZ",
    "vouchers" :[
        {
            "voucherCode": "VOUCHERA",
            "amount": 1000
        },
        {
            "voucherCode": "VOUCHERB",
            "amount":23
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get the `vouchers` json array and pass it as a request payload to another API.  Currently I am doing this to get the `vouchers` array:

```golang
type vouchers struct {
    Vouchers []interface{} `json:"vouchers" form:"vouchers"`
}

vouchers := vouchers{}
json.Unmarshal(reqBody, &vouchers)
```

This gives me the `vouchers` object but how do I convert this to an `io.Reader` object and send it as a payload to another API?

Comment: Instead of `[]interface{}` you could use `json.RawMessage` and then `bytes.NewReader([]byte(vouchers.Vouchers))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out one way to solve it, thanks to some help on the Discord Gophers channel. `vouchers` json object can be unmarshalled into a field of type  `json.RawMessage`, which then can be passed in `bytes.NewReader`.

```golang
type vouchers struct {
    Vouchers json.RawMessage `json:"vouchers" form:"vouchers"`
}

vouchers := vouchers{}
json.Unmarshal(reqBody, &vouchers)
```

This can be later passed as a payload to another API using `bytes.NewReader(vouchers.Vouchers)`.